# Tracking down a literary quote about grammar

Tags: quote-source

I once read a quote that goes something like,

> We should all be grateful to grammarians for saving us in fifty years
>   from a grievous error.

I think it's by Proust, but Google doesn't seem to agree. Anyone know this or can find it?

I'll take any quote with a similar sentiment, really. The basic idea of it is that grammar may be annoying and nitpicky now, but one day you'll find yourself in a situation where being grammatically precise will be crucial.

Comment: I'll take any quote with a similar sentiment, really.

Comment: The basic idea is that grammar may be annoying and nitpicky now, but one day you'll find yourself in a situation where being grammatically precise will be crucial.